# Laravel -> Make query based on model's method result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have 2 tables and models.
So, 1 CV has Many Diplomas. Relationship is defined in models.

In my edit action :

```
$cv = Cv::where('link', '=', $link)->firstOrFail();
```

Then If I'm calling relationship function `diplomas` like here :

```
 $cvDiploms = $cv->diplomas;
 return $cvDiploms;
```

It returns me array of JSON objects.

Now, I'm trying to make a query like :

```
 $deletedDiplomas = $cv->diplomas->whereNotIn('image', $request['test-diploma'])->get();
```

It returns me that error :

> Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get(), called in
>   /home/name/project/app/Http/Controllers/CvsController.php on line 272
>   and defined

How should I call that query to get all `Cv's diplomas`, where `'image'` is `not in $request['test-diploma']` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$cv->diplomas` automatically calls `get()` on the query, so it returns a collection.  You are then calling `get()` again, but the Collection method `get()` requires an argument.

You need to write `$cv->diplomas()` (referencing the function not the attribute) to fetch the query, which you can then filter before calling `get()`

```
$deletedDiplomas = $cv->diplomas()->whereNotIn('image', $request['test-diploma'])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to make a query on an array object. You should use the relation itself to make the query. Try this:

```
$deletedDiplomas = $cv->diplomas()
                      ->whereNotIn('image', $request['test-diploma'])
                      ->get();
```